# Permitted values at checkbox in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

first, sorry for my bad english, i don't like for translators rs, 
well, i'm trying to recover a id at checkbox field using dinamic id content, 
i'm using this in datatable code for my rails application:

```html
"<input type='checkbox' id='#{ record.archetype_file_name }'>",
```

and it will be returned at my browser like as

```html
<input id="CEN-EN13606-ENTRY.Deficiencias.v1.adl" type="checkbox">,
```

,

my doubt is: these points and other special characters vain to stop me from using this id and stuff , what do you suggest me ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the html `id` to be dynamic with the content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: If you need to get dynamic `id`s in rails, you can use the `ActionView::RecordIdentifier`. This provides you with some methods like: `div_for`, `dom_name`, `dom_id`, etc... In your case, I think what you want is the `dom_id`. [You can check the documentation out here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html)